# VBA: Referencing a Pivot Table by name rather than index number

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple question. What is the syntax for referencing a pivot table in VBA by its *name* rather than its index number?

For example, I could write this line like this:

`With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables(1).PivotFields("InvestorNumber")
End With`

But I need to write it like this:

`With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("InvestorNumber") End With`

Writing it the second way errors-out with "subscript not in range" although "PivotTable1" definitely exists on this worksheet and the pivot table's name is definitely "PivotTable1"

Any thoughts on what is wrong with the syntax?

MSDN says it can be referenced by name, but doesn't give an example of how you do it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivottables-object-excel

Thanks

Comment: It definitely should work (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-pivottables-method-excel). There's an exemple in the provided link, using name reference.

Comment: Do you have a macro free .xlsx  to share with dummy data that can reproduce the problem? The above appears correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. I was still using an index number to refer to the Worksheet and this was throwing the error. So this doesn't work:

`With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("InvestorNumber")
End With`

While it appears this does work:

`With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("InvestorNumber")
End With`

If you want to use names rather than index numbers in the object reference, then names have to be used for all members; you can't use a mix of indexes and names apparently.

Comment: Or your actual first sheet was not "Sheet1" in the workbook? Haven't tested but I would expect you to be able to use Index.